# Unable to start postgresql server [could not bind IPv4 socket: Permission denied]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sockets, server, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to start my PostgreSQL 9.4 database server on my local Windows machine via Ubuntu console. I'm running the command `sudo service postgresql start`, but I'm receiving the following error output:

```
The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2020-02-25 09:57:30.216 CST [497] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Permission denied
2020-02-25 09:57:30.216 CST [497] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2020-02-25 09:57:30.217 CST [497] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2020-02-25 09:57:30.217 CST [497] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets       [fail]
```

How do I check if another postmaster is already running on port 5432? If there is one, how would I stop it? Thank you!